# Bootstrap PHP Login

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I'm having issues with my PHP login. I'm using bootstrap and When ever I click 'Login' nothing is happening. If I am correct it should be submitting me to a blank page.

Any suggestions?

Bootstrap Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
              <form action="submit.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
              </div>
              <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
            </fieldset>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];



if($username&&$password)
{

  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "sfmin", "password") or die("Error"); 
  mysql_select_db("rothienc_login") or die("error");

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


  if($numrows!=0)
  {


  }
  else 
    die("That user doesn't exist!");

}
else
 die("ERROR");


?>
```

Comment: Probably want to remove database credentials from the question

Comment: That `if` is weak, you probably want to use `if (!empty($username))` etc.Also you need to fill `if($numrows!=0)`. It is empty in your example. Also you should use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*,

Answer (score 6):

You defined `<form>` twice:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
```

Change this to just one element:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
```

Make your username `<input>` name attribute lowercase:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
```

Escape your SQL query properly:

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <form action="submit.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
          </div>
          <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" >
        </fieldset>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

php:

```
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sfmin", "password", "rothienc_login") or die("Error"); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users");

 if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password'])
 {
  // User exists
  $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($connect, $query);


  if($numrows!=0)
  {


  }
  else 
  die("That user doesn't exist!");

  }
  else
  die("ERROR");

  } else {
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
  }


  ?>
```

this checks if the submit button was clicked `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` then it checks for user match database records and then if it is correct it logs the user in also remember to set session variables

Answer (score -1):

If you want a beauty and modern Login whit PHP and this, man! use JQuery Ajax. 
In the input button change the type "Submit" for "button" and you need generate a basic ajax whit jquery.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'URL_PHP_LOGIN.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {user: user, pass: pass},
                success: function(html){

                  alert(html)//Alert when the login is correct.

                }

            });
```